# Как лучше реализовать многоуровневую реферальную систему для выплат рефералов?

Tags: php, рекурсия

Сейчас я представляю себе так:
в БД каждому пользователю сделать ячейку `referal` т.е хранить id пригласившего пользователя. 
И запустить функцию с рекурсией, которая будет брать значение `referal` выплачивать ему %, и до тех пор пока не закончится ветка с рефералами. 
Как вы считаете это решение нормальное? Может вы что предложите ?

Comment: А погрешности не слишком большие будут?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать модель [Nested Sets (вложенные множества)](http://zabolotnev.com/mysql-nested-sets)